# How to fix "StorageDataError: BotoClientError: Out of space for destination file" error in boto3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I'm ran a job in AWS which used `boto`.But the `boto` report the following error:

```
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1724, in get_contents_to_filename
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029        response_headers=response_headers)
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1662, in get_contents_to_file
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029        response_headers=response_headers)
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1494, in get_file
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029        query_args=None)
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1562, in _get_file_internal
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029        '%s' % fp.name)
b98811ab-e0da-4f05-96eb-c73f2b7a6029    StorageDataError: BotoClientError: Out of space for destination file /var/lib/toil/toil-e7178a87-50ae-43c0-8566-220a6258b0d6-6e3cb1d2-4939-44c9-a78b-5e0fb38f7fbc/tmp9JuAm1/c5918878-73c6-44a3-82c3-6a61c2261e79/tmpdVLQ9f.tmp
```

I'm wondering what the `out of space` means.Is the `out of space` referred to "out of memory" or `out of storage`?How should I fix this error?Increase the memory or sorage of EC2 instance?
Thank you!

Comment: From exception, it could be fairly concluded that its `"out of storage"`? Hence, you need to increase the storage.  Very limited information has been provided, its hard to tell what exact place you have to fix, but definitely the increasing the `storage` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your  comment！I have fixed this problem and it is indeed a problem of out of storage.

Comment: good to know that it same issue as stated.